# How to create password field for checkout page for account creation in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have to do account creation on checkout process with password field in checkout page, Please anyone suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Ranganathan , Did you get any solution for this??

Comment: Yes....What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I need to show password and confirm password fields in checkout page [for guest customers], after place an order, customer should be created with password.Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any extension in checkout like one page checkout? or any other?

Comment: Not using any extension for checkout, default Magento checkout only.

Comment: Ahh...Need some time to work on this...

Comment: Ok, please update here once you got solution.

Comment: did you get any solution guys?